# Insert array of objects in Any

Tags: java, corba

I'm working with corba and I have a problem:
I have to put an array of object in an any object.
I can do it when i'm using simple types, for example double.

```
DoubleSeqHelper.insert(Any, double[])
```

The problem is that I'm not able to do the same with files that I have defined in my IDL..

Let's suppose that I have a class A. I can use `AHelper` for putting one instance of A in an Any object.

```
AHelper.insert(Any, A)
```

But how can i put an array of A in an Any object?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution1:

Create a sequence/array of any's.

Insert one A into one any element of array/sequence.

Then insert complete Any sequence/array into a single Any.

OR

Solution2:

Define Array of A  in interface. 
Then you can directly insert Array of A into any.

Comment: do you mean define array of A in the IDL?